# postgresql - creae view showing showing time as human readable

Tags: sql, postgresql, apache-nifi

Looking for some guidance on creating a view or running query which will convert epoch time to datetime. End game to use grafana to query the table, but it does not recognise the time format.
Example of output
"1665412979.398410"

"1665412979.370040"

"1665412979.158181"

I've gone through dozens of options found in the group and online, but cant seem to get the results with date and time.

SELECT (time_now || ' second')::interval::time without time zone,
seems close but no date.

Any input would be appreciate. The data is via an API, and written to PostgreSQL via nifi PutDatabaseRecord.

Comment: Use the `to_timestamp` function.

Comment: Something like this `select to_timestamp(1665412979.398410)`

Comment: Hi , Thanks for the suggestions, solution worked with the to_timestamp                         SELECT to_timestamp(time::double precision / 1000) AS time